# Kotlin - Generic function storing incorrect type in map successfully

Tags: generics, kotlin

Consider the following code:

```
val myarray = arrayListOf("hello", "world")
println(myarray)
println(myarray::class.java.name)

val arrayString = mapper.writeValueAsString(myarray)
println(arrayString)
println(arrayString::class.java.name)

val myMap = HashMap<String, String?>()
myMap["key"] = JsonPath.read<String>(arrayString, "$")

println(myMap["key"])
println(myMap["key"]!!::class.java.name)
```

This code creates an ArrayList containing the values "hello" and "world", converts the list to a json string, reads the root element of json (which is a generic function told to return a string) and stores it in a HashMap

This code compiles and runs without error and produces the following output:

```
[hello, world]
java.util.ArrayList
["hello", "world"]
java.lang.String
["hello","world"]
net.minidev.json.JSONArray
```

How does `myMap["key"]` return a `JSONArray`? (recall that myMap was declared as `<String, String?>`)

Kotlin its type checked at compile time, but because the generic function `JsonPath.read` is told to return a `String`, compilation happens fine.

The `JsonPath.read` then seems to violate its contract and returns a `JSONArray` instead of a `String`. Kotlin does not seem to type check this and allows storage of the `JSONArray` within a `Map<String, String?>`.

No errors are produced unless I attempt to use `myMap["key"]` as a `String`

**NOTE**

This problem can be resolved by changing the line that reads the json to:

```
myMap["key"] = ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(JsonPath.read<String>(arrayString, "$"))
```

**EDIT**

Code example not using json madness:

```
fun <T> myFun(): T {
  return 7 as T
}

fun test() {
  val map = HashMap<String, String?>()
  map["key"] = myFun<String>()
  println(map["key"])
  println(map["key"]!!::class.java.name)
}

returns:
7
java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: You have a list of strings and trying to parse it as a string. How should kotlin or java handle this? Quote from the [docs](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#what-is-returned-when): `When using JsonPath in java its important to know what type you expect in your result.`

Comment: @aweson I would expect kotlin to say "hey, you just tried to store a JSONArray into a map expecting strings" or JsonPath to say "hey you requested a string, but this isn't a string".

in the system where I discovered this, users can pass in a set of paths and expect a map back of key=path and value=json string. I cannot know what type is at the path.

the issue I'm interested in here is not my bad code, but that kotlin allowed a non string type to be stored in a map of strings successfully.

Comment: JsonPath promised that it will return String. It lied, because it does not have access to the actual type you've requested (type erasure) and instead of checking that the result is a `String`, it just returns an object and says "You asked for T - here is something I found and hopefully it is T".

Comment: I'm ok with JsonPath lieing (though I feel it shouldn't be allowed to do that), but I feel like by the time we get to the put method of map the type should be defined and the map be like "wait a sec. thats not a string". Using generics, I can basically abuse a map<String, String?> and treat it as a map<String, Any>

Comment: "wait a sec. thats not a string" - if Map would be able to perform this check, why `JsonPath` is unable to check the type of the object it is going to return? This is just how generics implemented. You do not have access to the generic type at the runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generic type information is erased at runtime](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-erasure).

So basically just taking your updated example and translating it to what it will be at runtime (simplified):

```
fun myFun(): Any = 7

fun test() {
  val map = HashMap<Any, Any?>()
  map["key"] = myFun()
  println(map["key"])
  println(map["key"]!!::class.java.name) // of course: Integer!
}
```

Note also that you were using an [unchecked cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#unchecked-casts) here (and most probably also `JsonPath.read` is using it), which basically is the reason why the compiler has no real chance to catch the problem. Or in other words, by using an [unchecked cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#unchecked-casts) (`7 as T`) you basically say to the compiler "hey... I know what I am doing, don't bother"... and so it doesn't bother ;-)

Comment: so it kind of sounds like generics really only assign types to vals and vars that use the object the generic is on at compile time, but the object themselves have their generic types ignored (or erased) at run time

Comment: I don't understand the first part of your comment... but I try to clarify nonetheless... the generic type is used by the compiler as long as it can be used and generally helps you write type-safe code... but as soon as you use something like an unchecked cast (and even more so if you don't really know what you are doing) then generic types can really hurt ... you then can have anything in there and the compiler will never warn you (except for the unchecked casts)... so as an important side-note: whenever you can: omit unchecked casts... or be aware of the consequences...

Comment: what I meant is if I have `val something = myFun<String>()`, `something` will be of type String. And then subsequently error at runtime when an Int is passed to it.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Using your `myFun`-function it will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime, because the `7` (`Int`) can not be cast to `String`. Regarding `var`: if you do not specify the type of `something` to be `Any?` a reassignment will also not succeed at compile time nor runtime as the first assignment will basically determine the type of `something`.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem is tracked as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12451.

Currently Kotlin doesn't check the result of a generic method call before passing it to another generic method, even if at the call site it knows the reified type of the generic type parameter. This behavior is same as in Java, though there could be some room for improvement.